# Convert like raster cell values to a polygon?

Tags: arcmap

I have a population density raster and would like to create 5 polygons from the 5 natural break (jenks) classification ranges. 1 polygon for each classification range. I'm using ArcMap10 and have all of the Extensions enabled in the ToolBox to my disposal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To get your raster data to represent natural breaks classification, you'll need to use the [Reclassify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sr000000.htm) tool in the spatial analyst toolbox (make sure you have enabled this extension under Customize -> Extensions).  You can adjust the symbology of your original raster data to display in natural breaks, or whatever classification you wish, then record the ranges for each class and use them to input into your reclassify tool.  Once your data is reclassified you want to use the [Raster to Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000) tool in the Conversion toolbox, then the [Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool in the Data Management toolbox to consolidate your polygons into one per class.